# Built.io integration failed in iOS application due to ambiguous method call error

Tags: sdk, integration, built.io

I am trying to integrate built.io in iOS application using Xcode 9.1 and swift 4 but it failed due to ambiguous save call error, although I have only called this method once still it says ambiguous call. I am unable to identify the problem.
I referred this [link](https://docs.built.io/quick-start#swift) to integrate sdk in iOS :

Code used is

import UIKit
import Contentstack
import BuiltIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
func built(){
    var builtApplication : BuiltApplication = Built.application(withAPIKey: "")
    var pc : BuiltClass = builtApplication.class(withUID: "test")
    var projectObject:BuiltObject = pc.object()

    projectObject.save { (responseType, err) in //ambiguous error here on save call
        if err != nil {
            print("Err")
        } else {
            print("Success")
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

}

[image]

I have installed sdk in project using cocoapod. Below image contains application screenshot that shows error. I am using BuiltObject class object to call save method but when I jump into save method it takes me to method of BuiltKeyStore class, and I completely don't understand why? Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste the code itself in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass **completionBlock** as a parameter instead of **inline**.
Try the below code which works fine for Swift 3.2 & 4,

```
    let completionBlock:BuiltRequestCompletionHandler = { (responseType:BuiltResponseType, error:Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Err")
        } else {
            print("Success")
        }
    }

    projectObject.save(completionBlock)
```

Give it a try that should definitely work.